# What code could recreate this excel bar graph in R? (Don't worry about the positive.or.negative column)

Tags: r

Here is the table in Excel:

[image: Table of data and graph in Excel]

Here is my head(df) in R:

[image: Head(df) in R]

Here is my Code:

```
##Import CSV
df<-read.csv("Sentiment Matrix.csv")
##Check top of df
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Journey.Area = c("Installing", "Using Product", 
"Installing", "Delivery", "Installing", "Delivery"), Experience.Framework = c("People/Associate", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"People/Associate"), Postive.or.Negative = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
##Plot????
```

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried and any relevant errors. If you cannot post your data, then please post code for creating representative data.

Comment: You can make a grouped horizontal bar chart using the [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) package.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is a great tool, but the people here needs that you "help us help you". Please consider editing your question.

That said, you could use the great `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Journey.Area, y = Positive.or.Negative, fill = Experience.Framework))+
       geom_col()+
       coord_flip()
```

Comment: This is so close to what I'm looking for. I want the y = count of occurrence though rather than the Positive.or.Negative. Is there a way to change that up?

Comment: try `geom_bar`. **Please** edit your question above as suggested ...